# Proving that $f(z)=1/\Gamma(z)$ has order 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

There is a theorem that says that the convergent exponent of the zeros of a entire function is never greater than its order, so i'm traying to use that.

The zeros of the reciprocal gamma function are the poles of the $\Gamma$, thatss form se sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ $\{0,-1,-2,-3,...\}$ and the exponent $\lambda$ is the greatest lower bound such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|a_{n}|^{\lambda}}$$

converges, well we all know thats form the $\lambda$-harmonic series that converges for $\lambda >1$, so all the exponents $p=1+\epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0$ is a lower bound for the order $\rho$ of $f$, but if $p=1$ the serie diverges so how can i conclude that $\rho =1$?

Comment: Did you mean $a_n$ are the zeros counted with multiplicity of the entire function $f(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$  ? (here they are all simple so it doesn't change anything, and it is not immediately obvious $f(z)$ is entire, you need to prove things like the reflection formula). $\rho = \inf_{\lambda } \{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|a_{n}|^{\lambda}} $ converges $\}= 1$. Also you need to say something about the type (for example $e^{e^z}\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ has the same zeros)

Comment: exactaly, but by that $\rho$ is lower than any $\lambda$ and then we get a absurd by the theorem

Comment: Nobody said $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|a_{n}|^{\lambda}}$ converges for $\lambda = \rho$, ie. the $\inf$ doesn't have to be in the set.

Comment: but by the logic of the theorem if $\lambda \leq \rho$ then the serie should converge for $\lambda=\rho$

Comment: You meant $\lambda \ge \rho$. As you see no..${}$

Comment: In the same way $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  z^n $ converges for  $|z| < 1$ but not for $|z|=1$